# the difference of include and require in torch

Tags: torch

What's the difference between require and include in torch(lua)? what it did in the back when we call include or require?
for example:

```
 include('util/test.lua')
 require('util/test.lua')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torch include is simply Lua [dofile](http://luatut.com/dofile.html) as can be seen in the Torch [source](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/init.lua#L53):

```
function torch.include(package, file)
   dofile(torch.packageLuaPath(package) .. '/' .. file)
end
```

On the other hand, Lua [require](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) is used to load modules. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144564/what-are-the-differences-between-dofile-and-require-in-lua) answer.

> Roughly, require does the same job as dofile, but with two important
>   differences. First, require searches for the file in a path; second,
>   require controls whether a file has already been run to avoid
>   duplicating the work. Because of these features, require is the
>   preferred function in Lua for loading libraries.

Answer (score 0):

in require if the compiler cannot find the specific file compiler will stop to compile other part off the code

but in include if the compiler cant find the file ,begin to compile other parts of code with no errror